# VESA BIOS Extensions: How to Change Resolution?

Tags: video, grub, protected-mode, vesa

I just finished writing a small boot loader and kernel that switches into protected mode and sets up a basic physical and virtual memory manager:

[image]

Currently, I'm displaying text onto the screen by writing to the video address `0xB8000` in memory. However, I would like to increase the TTY resolution, the way GRUB does (through, I think, the `GRUB_GFXMODE` flag).

#### How do I increase the screen resolution in protected mode?

I've tried looking into the GRUB source code (regarding the parts that concern VBE and `vbeinfo`); however, I don't understand how it's actually working. Is there any guide online for how to do this? (My search on OSDev.org didn't yield much, but it's possible I missed it.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS-DOS - Is it possible to program 24 bit graphics?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460508/ms-dos-is-it-possible-to-program-24-bit-graphics)